# example of two disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\Bbb R$ so that $A \cup B$ and $A$ are both open in $\Bbb R$ but $B$ is not open in $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

In a question I recently encountered is as follows that give an example of two disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\Bbb R$ so that $A \cup B$ and $A$ are both open in $\Bbb R$ but $B$ is not open in $\Bbb R$.

I'm clueless  so far. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Hint: $A=(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$.

Comment: Actually, take any connected open set and call it $A \cup B$. Now take a nonempty proper open subset of it, call it $A$. You will probably have that $B$ is not open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

$A=(0,4)$ and $B=[4,5)$

Comment: Sorry... I edit !

Answer (score 2):

Take $A=(-\infty, 0)$ and $B=[0,\infty).$

Answer (score 0):

$$A=(-1,1), B=(-\infty,-1]\cup [1,\infty)$$

Note that $A$ and  $A\cup B$ = $\Bbb R$ are  open but  B is not open.